# How to subscribe to an event dynamically using anonymous methods?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, delegates, anonymous-methods

I'm creating a number of `UserControl`s dynamically using `LoadControl(String)` and want to subscribe to an event of each of them.

All my controls inherits a common `Interface` that require an implementation of a common `Event`:

```
public interface IObjectProcessor
{
    event EventHandler<ObjectProcessedEventArgs> ObjectProcessed;
}
```

So I do next on my page loading event:

```
protected void Page_Load()
{
   switch(Request["type"])
   {
     case "user":
     {
        LoadControl("AddUser.ascx", delegate(object sender, ObjectProcessedEventArgs e)
        {
           // do something
        });
        break;
     }
   }
}

private void LoadControl(string path, Action<object, ObjectProcessedEventArgs> action)
{
    var control = (IObjectProcessor)LoadControl(path)
    control.ObjectProcessed // here!
}
```

How to subscribe a deleagte to this event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `Action<object, ObjectProcessedEventArgs>` to `EventHandler<ObjectProcessedEventArgs>`:

```
private void LoadControl(string path, EventHandler<ObjectProcessedEventArgs> handler)
{
        var control = (IObjectProcessor)LoadControl(path)
        control.ObjectProcessed += handler;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
control.ObjectProcessed += action
```

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Action<object,ObjectProcessedEventArgs>' to 'EventHandler<ObjectProcessedEventArgs>'

Comment: create explicit declartion of delegate(object sender, ObjectProcessedEventArgs e) and use it as input type